# why curl says this URL as dead?

Tags: php, url, curl, monitoring

I am trying to monitor URL's which are in my database. I an using CURL to determine if the url is still alive or not. I gave a simple condition in `if` clause as `if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300)
{ 
 return 1;
 }` but when i pass `http://apps.facebook.com/chkouabeaddeb` to CURL it returns `0`. but if I put the same URL in browser it redirects to the application. what can i do to make CURL send me correct response ?

Comment: What HTTP status are you getting from curl? That should give you a hint. It's probably giving you a 300-class redirection, which you're saying is a "dead" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl -I http://apps.facebook.com/chkouabeaddeb
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /chkouabeaddeb/
```

302 (a redirect) is greater than 300, so your code and Facebook are both working exactly as programmed.

Comment: You'll likely want to include 301 too. You should treat 400 and up as non-functioning links, not 300+.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting a 300-class redirection status from curl, which you're assuming means "dead". It doesn't, it means you need to handle it as a redirection.